# Relatório a partir de um formulário, sem banco de dados

Tags: c#, relatório, impressão

Minha dúvida é, consigo gerar um relatório (não sei se posso chamar assim) ou comprovante que seja algo assim:

---

Relatório: Data de pagamento
Cliente: xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx
Data de pagamento: xx/xx/xxxx

---

Assinatura

Seria um layout bem simples basicamente isso que fiz acima sem usar banco de dados enfim, seria preenche os valores e imprimir o que está preenchido e fim.

O layout do programa é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso? E se é possível, pois pesquisei alguns e não entendi muito bem, visto que o meu VisualStudio não possui o `CrystalReports`

**UPDATE**

Classe Impressao.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Impressao
{
    public static class Funcoes
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gera a impressão de um texto
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_textoImpressao">string para impressão</param>
        /// <param name="_font">Fonte da impressão</param>
        /// <param name="_impressora">Nome da impressora, informar null ou "" para padrão do windows</param>
        public static void ImprimirString(string _textoImpressao, Font _font, string _impressora)
        {
            string[] linhas = _textoImpressao.Split('\n');
            Queue<string> filaLinhas = new Queue<string>();
            foreach (string l in linhas)
            {
                filaLinhas.Enqueue(l);
            }

            PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
            p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
            {
                Font printFont = _font;
                float linesPerPage = 0;
                float yPos = 0;
                int count = 0;
                float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
                float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
                string line = null;

                //Calcular o número de linhas por página
                linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
                   printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

                // Imprime cada linha do texto
                while (count < linesPerPage && filaLinhas.Count > 0)
                {
                    line = filaLinhas.Dequeue();
                    yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
                    ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, yPos, new StringFormat());
                    count++;
                }

                // Se existir mais linhas, gera outra página.
                if (line != null && filaLinhas.Count > 0)
                    ev.HasMorePages = true;
                else
                    ev.HasMorePages = false;
            };

            PrintDialog diag = new PrintDialog();
            diag.Document = p;
            diag.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = _impressora;
            if (diag.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                p.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Botão gerar impressão: (Tento chamar a classe mas não acha)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Impressao b = new Impressao();
            DateTime dataPagamento = DateTime.Now;
            string clienteNome = "Fulano da Silva Sauro";
            string texto = "Relatório de Pagamento" + "\n";
            texto += "Cliente: " + clienteNome + "\n";
            texto += "Data Pagamento: " + dataPagamento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

            FuncoesImprimir.ImprimirString(texto, new Font("Consolas", 12f, FontStyle.Regular), null);
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como vai imprimir ? impressora "normal", matricial, dual (Térmica) ?

Comment: Em uma impressora normal, folha A4, o que preciso é que abra o relatorio com os dados preenchidos já coloco para imprimir e fim

Comment: seu comando deve ficar algo como `Impressao.Funcoes.ImprimirString(..);`

Comment: Veja como fica, parece que não acha

Comment: Ata entendi, agora parou.. eu tava tentando instanciar a classe, mas fazendo do jeito que disse deu,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pensando em uma impressão simples, somente texto e que não seja necessário nenhum software adicional tipo crystal reports, você pode usar essa função que gera a impressão pelo próprio C#. Basta informar o texto que será impresso, a fonte, e a impressora que será utilizada para imprimir (opcional):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SeuNameSpace
{
    public static class Funcoes
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gera a impressão de um texto
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_textoImpressao">string para impressão</param>
        /// <param name="_font">Fonte da impressão</param>
        /// <param name="_impressora">Nome da impressora, informar null ou "" para padrão do windows</param>
        public static void ImprimirString(string _textoImpressao, Font _font, string _impressora)
        {
            string[] linhas = _textoImpressao.Split('\n');
            Queue<string> filaLinhas = new Queue<string>();
            foreach (string l in linhas)
            {
                filaLinhas.Enqueue(l);
            }

            PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
            p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
            {
                Font printFont = _font;
                float linesPerPage = 0;
                float yPos = 0;
                int count = 0;
                float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
                float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
                string line = null;

                //Calcular o número de linhas por página
                linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
                   printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

                // Imprime cada linha do texto
                while (count < linesPerPage && filaLinhas.Count > 0)
                {
                    line = filaLinhas.Dequeue();
                    yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
                    ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, yPos, new StringFormat());
                    count++;
                }

                // Se existir mais linhas, gera outra página.
                if (line != null && filaLinhas.Count > 0)
                    ev.HasMorePages = true;
                else
                    ev.HasMorePages = false;
            };

            PrintDialog diag = new PrintDialog();
            diag.Document = p;
            diag.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = _impressora;
            if (diag.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                p.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para utilizar o código:

```
        DateTime dataPagamento = DateTime.Now;
        string clienteNome = "Fulano da Silva Sauro";
        string texto = "Relatório de Pagamento" + "\n";
        texto += "Cliente: " + clienteNome + "\n";
        texto += "Data Pagamento: " + dataPagamento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        FuncoesImprimir.ImprimirString(texto, new Font("Consolas", 12f, FontStyle.Regular), null);
```

Comment: Como uso este código? Preciso criar dentro de um .cs? Por no botão de gerar?

Comment: cria um CS e cola esse código todo dentro dele, só lembra de alterar o namespace pro seu

Comment: Porque não consigo chamar a classe que criei no formulário? Ai da erro na linha d `FuncoesImprimir`

Comment: troca `namespace Impressao` por `namespace ProjetoFinal` e é uma classe estática, não precisa da instância `b = new Impressao();` só chamar exatamente como coloquei aqui acima

Comment: Deu certo mano, era o que precisava mesmo, agora vou adaptar ao que preciso :) muito obrigado!