# Imprimir na impressora não fiscal Elgin i7 c#

Tags: c#, winforms, impressão

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema PDV e preciso fazer impressão de cupons! Estou em posse de uma impressora não fiscal da elgin modelo i7. Já estou há horas procurando uma forma de imprimir um cupom a partir de um Relatório (.rdlc) que eu montei, mas nunca consigo imprimir, a impressão dá erro (não há detalhes sobre qual o erro). Já procurei API, .DLL no site da Elgin e nada também ... Já tentei inúmeras formas e nada dá certo!! Alguém tem alguma solução para fazer essa impressão?

PS: usando o programa ElginUtility eu já consegui imprimir, mas são só papeis de testes. Usando PosPrinterTester também consigo. O que eu quero é que meu programa também consiga, que por algum motivo não funciona!

Comment: Você quer imprimir cupons fiscais em uma impressora não fiscal ? como assim ?

Comment: erro meu, desculpa! kkk

Comment: Opa! no Paraná e alguns estado desde 2016 você pode  usar NFCe https://arquivei.com.br/blog/entenda-o-que-e-a-nfce/ , essa impressora pode imprimir já que não precisa homologar como no ECF.

Comment: excelente artigo @alxwca ! Sabe se existe alguma Dll ou alguma maneira que possa fazer a conexão entre meu programa e essa impressora para que eu possa imprimir as informações, como por exemplo o QR Code? Eu consegui utilizá-la somente pelos comandos de SerialPort e infelizmente só consegui imprimir linhas de textos, como num console.

Comment: Ainda não vi nenhuma dll pronta, você ira ter que construir segundo parametrização desta impressora.

Comment: normalmente essas impressoras não fiscais funcionam da mesma forma que outras impressoras no spooler do windows, só mandar impressão...

Comment: algum progresso Messias ? Tenho uma resposta que também utilizo pra imprimir em outras impressoras não fiscais: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251032/69359 , mas se tratando de um `.rdlc` tente isso: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms252091.aspx

Comment: Cara, eu dei umas configuradas aqui e funcionou usando esse link ai da microsoft, mas havia esquecido de dar o feedback. Muito obrigado! :)